# How to find 1st occurrence of exact string in URL with regular expression

Tags: regex, url, web, analytics

Newbie here, please be gentle. I did search through multiple Q&As but did not find my answer (or something I can comprehend).

`/home.html?cm_mmc=var01-_-var02-_-var03-_-var04` (separated by "dash underscore dash")

Find the FIRST occurrence of "-_-" and replace it with "&new="

`/home.html?cm_mmc=var01&new=var02-_-var03-_-var04`

Find the FIRST occurrence of "-_-" again and replace it with "&newer="

`/home.html?cm_mmc=var01&new=var02&newer=var03-_-var04`

Find the FIRST occurrence of "-_-" again (3rd time) and replace it with "&newest="

`/home.html?cm_mmc=var01&new=var02&newer=var03&newest=var04`

I am looking for a regex statement that can find me the first occurrence of "-_-" (dash underscore dash).

THANK YOU VERY MUCH AHEAD OF TIME. I WILL PAY THIS FORWARD.

Comment: sorry! my underscores got stripped out. Each var(1..4) is separated by "-_-" (dash underscore dash)

Comment: Are you using Advanced Filtering?

Comment: No sir (and TY!). I am using "Search & Replace" with Filter Field: Request URI, Search String: [find 1st occurrence of "dash underscore dash"], and Replace String: [insert my own new parameter]. This is my objective at least...

Comment: For context, I'm looking to unify campaign tracking code in URL to use the same parameters instead of appending different ones from each web analytics platform (Google Analytics = UTM, Coremetrics = CM_MMC) etc.

Comment: Back again! Tried 2 different versions but did not work. Will try another mod to hwnd's solution below.

Comment: Thanks again hwnd! I got it to work using your answer. I did make a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find and replace those occurrences, you can try the following.

```
Search: ^([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-
Replace: \1&new=\2&newer=\3&newest=
```

Or using Advanced Filter:

```
Field A, Request URI: ^([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-
Output,  Request URI: $A1&new=$A2&newer=$A3&newest=
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! Unfortunately, no go. I only want to replace the first occurrence of "-_-" with a new parameter. Everything else in the URL I want to remain the same. Is this an example of something that makes sense to me but cannot be done?

Comment: Would your example only replace the "-_-" and nothing else? I want to preserve each var (var01, var02, var03, var04)?

Comment: It does preserve them.

Comment: Wowsers, now we're talking! Yes, this does look like it'll work. I will give it a go. Much appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this out: find `^cm_mmc=([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-([^-]+)-_-` and replacing with `utm_medium=\1&utm_source=\2&utm_campaign=\3&utm_content=` I will be back tomorrow once some data comes in. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'M BACK! Unfortunately doesn't seem like this worked using the Search & Replace method. I will be trying the Advanced Filter method instead. I wish there was a faster way to validate these filters...

Answer (score -1):

try following in javascript:

```
var oldURL = "/home.html?cm_mmc=var01-_-var01-_-var02-_-var03-_-var04";
var newURL = oldURL.replace(/-_-/g, "&utm_source=");
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Unfortunately, this is completed through the Google Analytics interface so I cannot run JS. I am only looking for a regex statement that will help "select" only the first occurrence of "-_-". Perhaps my instructions are unclear...